# execute mysql query and display results while reading

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database and i want to execute a query and while this query is being executed the data should be displayed in page.

so for example if i have 1,000 result row from the query result i want to display each row while the query is being executed instead of waiting till the query finishes executing then displaying them at once.

here is my php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
// Database Name
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$test_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM V_Posts where _PID > 100 and _PID < 10000");
while($CHECK_PCID_R = mysql_fetch_array($test_query))
{
    echo $CHECK_PCID_R['_PID'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

I tried

```
echo $CHECK_PCID_R['_PID'] . "<br />";
flush();
```

But it didn't work :(

Comment: You'll have to use `flush()` and similar functions to try and force PHP and the webserver to send any output to the client as it happens.

Comment: @MarcB How do i use the flush()? should i add it beneath my echo ?

Comment: @MarcB The problem is that PHP is still a blocking language. The database query will happen all at once. I am unaware of a way to cut it up without doing multiple queries, which would ultimately slow it down even further.

Comment: Your query has finished - it's looping PHP that's slowing down your page.

Comment: @justin: the individual mysql_*() calls block, but only for the duration of the call. the echo inside the loop will STILL execute as expected, and flushing after each echo will (most likely) send the output to the client. Even if the query calls didn't block, if you're sorting or filtering the query, you probably wouldn't get any results on-the-fly-anyways. can't return what isn't available.

Comment: i updated my question, please have another look

Comment: You should send every line from your array to your page using **AJAX**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One query will produce one dataset and you'll have all the data at once. If your query is slow any latency in displaying the data will be small compared to the delay in receiving it. Using `flush()` might force the server to send parts of the page, but you're really just tinkering at the edges.

If you want to break this down you'll have to run multiple queries, which will arguably be much slower since you'll be running the same query repeatedly. This will load the database server unnecessarily, and will achieve only a minor cosmetic effect.

If you use an AJAX call to retrieve your data you can display a 'loading' message while you wait. You could use multiple AJAX calls to display the data bit by bit - this is even worse than using multiple queries in the PHP script.